How to group and consolidate multiple rows into single rows in SQL Server?
I have a table that contains data about team members:
ID  Team Name    Role
1   1    Adam    Lead
2   1    Barbara Analyst
3   1    Connor  Logistics
4   2    David   Lead
5   2    Ethan   Logistics
6   3    Faith   Lead
7   3    George  Analyst
8   3    Hannah  Analyst

Rather than having each team member's data in its own row, I want to group them on the [Team] field and consolidate them into single rows like this:
Team 1st Member Name 1st Member Role 2nd Member Name 2nd Member Role 3rd Member Name 3rd Member Role
1    Adam            Lead            Barbara         Analyst         Connor          Logistics
2    David           Lead            Ethan           Logistics       NULL            NULL
3    Faith           Lead            George          Analyst         Hannah          Analyst

With requirements that each team can only have a maximum of 3 members. How could this logic be implemented in SQL Server?
I know that this is a very contrived requirement, but this is the formatting that is supported by the application that will be consuming my SQL data. The actual dataset has several more rows and repetitions of fields.
I've attempted to use pivot tables and dynamic SQL to solve this issue, but I couldn't figure out how to implemented the 'appending' of each group's fields into one single row.

Use conditional aggregation together with a ROW_NUMBER that splits them into groups. I'm pretty sure there are existing questions pretty much like this one this week even

You talk about an "application that will be consuming my SQL data". What application is it? Such tasks can often be done far better in the application than in plain SQL.

@JonasMetzler The consumer is a legacy COBOL system, handling this logic inside of the application currently doesn't seem to be an option.

Use ROW_NUMBER to order your members and then use CASE WHEN with aggregation:
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    team,
    name,
    role,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY team ORDER BY id) AS row_num
  FROM source_data
)

SELECT
  team,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN name END) AS name_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN role END) AS role_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN name END) AS name_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN role END) AS role_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN name END) AS name_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN role END) AS role_3
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY team

